# HTML Contact form not able to configure

Tags: javascript, html

I use a template to develop a website. There is a contact form in it which I am having trouble to use. I tried using sources finding from internet to set it to send email to address I want but to no avail.

Here is source for contact form page.

```
<form id="ContactForm">
    <div>
        <div class="wrapper"> <span>Your Name:</span>
            <input type="text" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper"> <span>Your E-mail:</span>
            <input type="text" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class="textarea_box"> <span>Your Message:</span>
            <textarea name="textarea" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
        </div> 
        <a href="#" class="button1" 
            onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">Send</a>
        <a href="#" class="button1" 
            onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()">Clear</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Your question is not really clear of what you want...

Comment: You need some form of action; a server side file in PHP or JSP or what-have-you.

Comment: this is code for the contact form. I want user when clicks button 'send', the msg entered in the text box to be sent to mail address I want. I am unable to find a code in php or js in the source folder of this web page or in other folders. As I told, I downloaded whole template of a website whose source code is in different folders. So please help me either in finding its action code OR write one.

Answer (score 1):

php require names for each form element to pass variables correctly, so you need to put a name tag in each input like

```
 <input type="text" name="name" id="id" />
```

second you need to define the form action, if you are sending parameters to another php file then you need to put the php file source like this:

```
<form  id="ContactForm" method="post" action="path/to/php">
```

if your are sending the parameters to the same page you can replace pat/to/php with `<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>` or simply type in the page's name.